# PHP / Wordpress - passing variables to create_function()

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, function

How do I pass a variable to create_function() ?

I have something like this:

```
function my_hook_function(){
  $var = 10;
  apply_filters('hook', $var);
  return $var;
}


$variable = 5;
$function = create_function('', 'return $variable;');

add_filter('hook', $function); 

echo my_hook_function();
```

but it doesn't work :(
theoretically the output should be 5

[add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) is a wordpress function that allows you to change stuff around :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first one is that you need to tell php what parameters get passed to the 'created' function, or reference them as a global inside of the body. The second is that you are expecting $var to be modified by the created function, but you are not passing it a reference. the created function simply returns the new variable and you do nothing with it.

```
function my_hook_function(){
  $var = 10;
  $var = apply_filters('hook', $var);
  return $var;
}

/* This will return 5 by dividing the passed value by 2 and returning the result */
$function = create_function('$variable', 'return $variable/2;');    
add_filter('hook', $function);
echo my_hook_function();

/* This will return 5 by referencing the global $variable */
$variable = 5;
$function = create_function('', 'global $variable; return $variable;');
add_filter('hook', $function);
echo my_hook_function();
```

Note that if you run this code exactly like this that *both* of the filters will be added to the 'hook' hook.

Answer (score 3):

```
$outsideVarName = 3434;
$function = create_function('$insideFunctionVarName', 'return $insideFunctionVarName;');
echo $function($outsideVarName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the manual for [create_function](http://php.net/create_function) the usage for passing `$variable` to the function would be as follows:

```
$variable = 3434;
$function = create_function('$v', 'return $v;');

echo $function($variable);
```

**EDIT**

Changed `$variable` inside the `create_function` call to make it a bit clearer of proper usage and avoid confusion.

**UPDATE**

Given the comment below, here is an updated version:

```
$variable = 3434;
$function = create_function('$v', 'return $v;');

function myTest($function, $var) {
    echo $function($var);
}

myTest($function, $variable); // should echo 3434
```

Not sure if that is what you want, I will refrain from guessing further till you show the actual context you are working in.

**Update 2**

Doing some research, is there a reason you do not just use it in this manner:

```
add_filter('something', create_function('$v', 'return $v;'));
```

From what I could find that should work...

Comment: hm.. the problem is that i can call $function like that :(
the created function is passed as a argument to another function, and needs to be a string...

Comment: Show your full code please or at least the context you are working in (IE the function you are passing $function to). I cannot accurately diagnose an issue if you only give me 1/4 of the problem.

Comment: ok, edited. it's wordpress-related, but I don't think wp has anything to do with the errors i get

Comment: Well it depends on how add_hook uses the variable $function. Chances are it thinks that $function should be the name of a function and not an actual function.

Comment: yes, the 2nd paramater should be the function name, but isn't that that $function is ?

Comment: A var_dump showed this: `var_dump($function); string(9) "lambda_1" ` so no, it is not the name of the function, I bet it is some sort of a reference, you can try calling `lambda_1($f, $var);`  but it will just return a function not found.

Comment: yes, i can't use create_function inside add_filter, because I need to add a remove_filter($function) later, and that needs the function name, which I don't have :)

Comment: So why not just make it a real function? From my research, I have not seen a way that makes it possible for you to use it as described, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is

```
$function = create_function('', "return $variable;");
```

or

```
$function = create_function('', 'return ' . $variable . ';');
```

i.e. you want to capture the value of the variable into the function when created. Since a number converted to a string is the same as its source representation, simply interpolating it into the source of the function is sufficient. For strings and arrays, some quoting will be necessary.

Comment: To return a static value you would not need a function... Point of the function possibly is to return a value based on some input param, otherwise you need to create a new function for every variable you want to pass it